# aws cloudfront custom ssl pricing for subdomain and www

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-acm

I have created two s3 origin website linked with cloudfront and used acm certificate.
But I recently found out pricing are different between https://admin.example.com and https://www.example.com.
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is charged for 20$ per day but admin site not. I am confused with these. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have added "[Dedicated IP custom SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-https-dedicated-ip-or-sni.html)" for CloudFront which is [$600 per month](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/), which comes to about $20 per day. It is rare to need your own dedicated IPs for CloudFront. Check if you need the feature, remove it if you don't need it. Instructions to remove it are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-switch-dedicated-to-sni.html).

From the pricing page.

> You pay $600 per month for each custom SSL certificate associated with
> one or more CloudFront distributions using the Dedicated IP version of
> custom SSL certificate support. This monthly fee is pro-rated by the
> hour. For example, if you had your custom SSL certificate associated
> with at least one CloudFront distribution for just 24 hours (i.e. one
> day) in the month of June, your total charge for using the custom SSL
> certificate feature in June will be (one day / 30 days) * $600 = $20

Comment: But I am using the same ssl for both distributions... Could you explain more details and where i can remove it, please? Thanks

Comment: I added a link about how to remove it to my answer. If that area of CloudFront really is exactly the same between the two distributions please add screenshots to your question so we can see. The $20 per day is strongly indicative of that $600 a month charge, but you haven't given us any information to diagnose this other than pricing information, which makes it difficult to help more.